# SLAMer and moving objects?

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

short:

just a short question: are the SLAM algorithms available to ROS (`gmapping`, `amcl`, `hector_slam`) capable of handling moving objects within the map?

longer description:

Consider having a "map" that is only defined by six cubes of 8x8x8cm placed in fixed positions around a rectangular area of 3x2m (three objects on each short side). However on the height of the laser scanner that creates that map there are up to three moving objects of about the same size of the six fixed cubes. They can screen (i.e. get in between) the fixed cubes from the laser scanner but most of the time hopefully will not.

I'll add details later if necessary...

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157646/slamer-and-moving-objects?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2014-04-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All approaches you mentioned use the static world assumption (i.e. moving objects are not modeled in any way), but they all should be robust against some violations of this assumption. Note AMCL is not a SLAM algorithm and uses a pre-built map, which has the advantage that it will not update the map estimate with moving objects. Both gmapping and hector_slam employ probabilistic grid mapping, so as long as the moving objects are really constantly moving, they will hopefully get filtered out during the SLAM process. If they stop, they become obstacles that are indistinguishable from your "true" obstacles, however.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-05-06**:
Currently I'm using AMCL with its pre-built map. This seems to be working pretty well. The thing is, the obstacles that are relevant and that I need to avoid are moving in a similar way like my robot (actually it's other robots that work in an unknown way). So I guess AMCL is way to go here. Thanks!

**Comment by [hunterlineage1](https://answers.ros.org/users/110678/hunterlineage1/) on 2023-04-21**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher @Hendrik Wiese I am using gmapping slam with multiple turtlebot3s in the same world. When they are moving past each other, my gmapping slam shows them as obstacles for each static snapshot of the laser scan and this messes up the OGM map building and localization of the robots. You mentioned that gmapping should be robust against some violations of the static world assumption assumption, so how can I fix this?